# How to get value into variable from JSON file using vbscript

Tags: json, vbscript

Hello I have a bit complex JSON file.
Is there a way to extract specific values from it?

In my case I would like to extract ID in to variable(variable = 73906) for KEY value "_unika_warnings_wysiwyg" under "meta_data"

```
{
    "id": 8473,
    "name": "mehurki",
    "slug": "mehurki",
    "permalink": "https://my.webshop.com/izdelek/mehurki/",
    "date_created": "2019-06-19T08:16:55",
    "date_created_gmt": "2019-06-19T07:16:55",
    "date_modified": "2020-07-23T07:42:02",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2020-07-23T06:42:02",
    "type": "simple",
    "meta_data": [
        {
            "id": 73906,
            "key": "_unika_warnings_wysiwyg",
            "value": "Item description"
        },
        {
            "id": 73907,
            "key": "_yoast_wpseo_metadesc",
            "value": "Item description"
        },
        {
            "id": 75324,
            "key": "_themify_builder_settings_json",
            "value": "[{\"element_id\":\"iyau326\",\"cols\":[{\"element_id\":\"t0vn327\",\"grid_class\":\"col-full\"}]}]"
        },
        {
            "id": 452344,
            "key": "_yith_wfbt_data",
            "value": {
                "products": "",
                "default_variation": "",
                "num_visible": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "bundle_layout": "",
    "bundled_by": [],
    "bundled_items": [],
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "https://my.webshop.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/8473"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://my.webshop.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Not something I'd recommend trying to do with VBScript, is this a standalone script requirement or are you using Classic ASP in a web application environment?

Comment: This is a  standalone script and this is the only option that I can use. I can call vbscript within ERP system. JSON file I get from webshop using api (also with vbscript). Now I need to extract this ID that I can post some changes for this ID